# Error on php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have read many post on this subject, but have not found the right answer. When i write any command `php artisan migrate` returns a result:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'adtmart1.shop_categories' doesn't exist (SQL: select * f
  rom `shop_categories`)


[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'adtmart1.shop_categories' doesn't exist
```

I would like to move the finished website made using Laravel on the local web server. I use Web server - opensever. There php version - 5.5, Mysql - 5.5. All commands i write of the console opensever. While replying, please, take into consideration that I am new in this field

Comment: Can you post migration file which causes the error? If you don't know which one doesn't work, try to run migrations one-by-one.

Comment: do you have "shop_categories" this table in `admart1` database?

Comment: It could also be that you're trying to do e.g. a `ShopCategory::all()` call in the constructor of a console command. If you do, it'll screw up artisan entirely if the table doesn't exist.

Comment: @AlankarMore the database is empty, you must first create a table?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin how to make migrate one?

Comment: @JoelHinz it does not know if honestly do not even know how to do an correctament migrate

Comment: Check in your migrations files where you are using this query "select * from  shop_categories" I mean where you are querying by using this Model of the shop_categories table and make sure before that migration files your shop_categories migration file must execute.

Comment: @AlankarMore as will all the migration process?

Comment: It is likely you have used `Schema::table` in one of your migrations rather than `Schema::create` and so it is trying to search for a table rather than create one.

Comment: @James how to write correctly Scheme::create  ?

Comment: Why are you guys trying to guess without seeing actual code? So much things can cause this error.

Comment: @Saahon have you used schema::create or schema:: table?

Comment: @James no, not use schema::create, schema::table

Answer (score 1):

You use `Schema::table` to alter an existing table, you are looking for `Schema::create` which is used to create a new table.

Alter your migrations to use `Schema::create` and you'll have no trouble running your migrations:

```
Schema::create('name_of_table', function(Blueprint $table) {
        {

            $table->increments("id",true);
            $table->string("username")->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->string("password")->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->string("email")->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I have of course used dummy columns and you would use your own.

More info on the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265202/laravel-4-migrate-base-table-not-found).

Comment: You write it in to your database/migrations files in the laravel source

Comment: I have all the file is: Schema::create

Comment: I think the error comes due to for some is incorrect code in the project

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll need to post migration code that causes the error. To do this, try to run migrations one-by-one. Remove all migrations from `/database/migrations` folder and then add first one (first by date it was created) back into `/database/migrations`. Then run `php artisan migrate`. If migrations was successful, do all steps for secons migration etc. When you see an error, you'll know that this one migrations causes it. Post it here please, so we could help.

Comment: First remove all files from the folder database/migrations. Then, through the openserver  console write command:  php artisan migrate:make create_users_table.   because in the folder database/migrations by date the very first  file was 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php

Comment: You do not need to create new migrations with `migrate:make`, you already have all migrations. Just add them one-by-one back to `/database/migrations` folder and run `php artisan migrate` command after each added migration.

Comment: still returns an error from the first file:    " [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'adtmart1.shop_categories' doesn't exist (SQL: select * f
  rom `shop_categories`)"

Comment: Of course it should cause an error. The important this is after what exactly migration? You need to find the problematic migration and post it here.

Comment: after the error I deleted first file and copied the second file and re write command "php artisan migrate", after this command also error